# c++ generate a string object performance?

Tags: c++, string

I want to send string object to server, the server accept json string only, so i need to generate different string object, with only replace some keywords.

I am very sensitive with latency.

i do this test to check latency:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int main() {
  char body[256];
  double qty = 1;
  // the following line make a big difference, 5us if remove it, else < 1us  !!!
  snprintf(body, sizeof(body), "{\"productType\": \"usdt-futures\", \"marginMode\": \"crossed\", \"orderType\": \"limit\", \"marginCoin\": \"USDT\", \"size\":\"%s\", \"price\":\"%s\", \"force\": \"%s\", \"clientOid\": \"%s\", \"side\": \"%s\", \"symbol\": \"%s\"}", "huangxinyu", "0.1", "0.11112", "asdasdas", "", (qty > 0 ? "sskiii" : "sell"));  // !!!!!!!!! this line make a huge difference in latency 
  snprintf(body, sizeof(body), "asdasdasdasd");
  timeval t;
  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  int usec = t.tv_usec;
  snprintf(body, sizeof(body), "{\"productType\": \"usdt-futures\", \"marginMode\": \"crossed\", \"orderType\": \"limit\", \"marginCoin\": \"USDT\", \"size\":\"%s\", \"price\":\"%s\", \"force\": \"%s\", \"clientOid\": \"%s\", \"side\": \"%s\", \"symbol\": \"%s\"}", "asd", "0.1111", "0.11112", "ioc", "", (qty > 0 ? "buy" : "sell"));
  gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
  printf("cost %ld\n", t.tv_usec - usec);
}
```

in my machine (with i9 10900k), with the compile command:

```
g++ -O3 main.cpp -o main
```

the latency is less than 1us.

but the difference happened when i remove this line:

```
snprintf(body, sizeof(body), "{\"productType\": \"usdt-futures\", \"marginMode\": \"crossed\", \"orderType\": \"limit\", \"marginCoin\": \"USDT\", \"size\":\"%s\", \"price\":\"%s\", \"force\": \"%s\", \"clientOid\": \"%s\", \"side\": \"%s\", \"symbol\": \"%s\"}", "huangxinyu", "0.1", "0.11112", "asdasdas", "", (qty > 0 ? "sskiii" : "sell"));
```

then the latency becomes 5 us, which is too high.

why the latency was decreased if add this line? and, is there any better method can generate this kind of keyword-changing string more effiectly?

thanks a lot

Comment: how did you compile? Which compiler? What compiler options? Most importantly, what optimization level?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai i added the compile command, thanks

Comment: The compiler managed to do some reusable work and/or retrieve some data outside the area you are measuring. For exact details you would have to delve into the assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the assembly, you will notice that this line

```
snprintf(body, sizeof(body), "asdasdasdasd");
```

is not compiled to a call to `snprintf`, but rather to a couple of simple `mov` instructions.

So the question immediately boils down to "why are the second and subsequent calls to `snprintf` much much faster than the first one"? This can be reaffirmed by sticking a loop around the entire body of `main`.

The answer should be obvious. The first call initializes whatever internal infrastructure of the C runtime `snprintf` needs. The second and subsequent ones don't.